# filtering json data in php laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I've a sample json data

```
"regions": [
      {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Region 1",
            "state_id": 1,
            "areas" :[ {
                   "id": 1,
                   "name": "area 1",
                   "region_id": 1},
                     {
                   "id": 2,
                   "name": "area 2",
                   "region_id": 1}

             ]
            
      },
      {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Region 2",
            "state_id": 1,
            "areas" :[ {
                   "id": 3,
                   "name": "area 3",
                   "region_id": 2},
                     {
                   "id": 4,
                   "name": "area 4",
                   "region_id": 2}

             ]
            
      }
]
```

How can I filter out the data the based on `id` in the `regions`? For example, if `id` is 2, then the response should be like

```
"regions": [
 {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Region 2",
            "state_id": 1,
            "areas" :[ {
                   "id": 3,
                   "name": "area 3",
                   "region_id": 2},
                     {
                   "id": 4,
                   "name": "area 4",
                   "region_id": 2}

             ]
            
      }
 ]
```

Comment: is `regions` json coming from database or other data source?

Comment: can't you just parse it via `json_decode()` and do `array_filter()`?

Comment: Other Data source. @MohsenNazari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `json_decode` that json string and then use `array_filter` method to filter regions

```php
$regions = json_decode('{"regions": 
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Region 1",
    "state_id": 1,
    "areas" :[ {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "area 1",
      "region_id": 1
    },{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "area 2",
      "region_id": 1
    }]
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Region 2",
    "state_id": 1,
    "areas" :[{
      "id": 3,
      "name": "area 3",
      "region_id": 2
    },{
      "id": 4,
      "name": "area 4",
      "region_id": 2
    }]
  }
]
}', true);

// Filter Region
$region_id = 2;
$filtered_regions = array_filter($regions['regions'], function($r) use ($region_id) {
  return $r['id'] == $region_id;
});

// Filter By Area Id
$area_id = 2;
$filtered_areas = array_filter($regions['regions'], function($r) use ($area_id) {
  $areas = array_filter($r['areas'], function($area) use ($area_id) {
    return $area['id'] == $area_id;
  });

  return count($areas) > 0;
});

return ['regions' => $filtered_regions];
```

Comment: I think I should use `$r->id` instead of $r['id']

Comment: You're right, If second parameter in `json_decode` is not set to true, then it will decode as object.

Comment: If I want to filter out areas, should I use `$r->areas->id` ?

Comment: No, Since `$r->areas` is array you can loop through it and find correct id, or get specific area by index. `$r->areas[0]->id`

Comment: I suggest to loop through it

Comment: `foreach($regions->areas as $areas) {
                array_filter($areas, function($r) use ($areaId) {
                    return $r->id == $areaId;
                  });
            }` Is it like this?

Comment: No, I edited my answer and you can see Filter By area

Comment: I couldn't thank you more but why are you using `count($areas) > 0`? When I tried your solution, It returned `null`.

Comment: Second array_filter returns areas which has id = 2, if count of that areas > 0 then region contains that area, so first array_filter resolves to true and returns that region

Comment: But it is still returning the whole data instead of filtered area data.

Comment: Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Area filtering is working for me. What does not works In you code? Can U share it?

Answer (score -1):

First apply **json_decode** on your json data then apply filter . If you want to get  an whole object from this response array , then write a function which will accept the id and return that object after filtering.

Comment: same answer with the accepted answer, duplicate