# laravel search JSON field valuee in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

the attribute column stores json

```
{
 "size":  [432, 433, 434], 
 "color": [17, 23, 56], 
 "brand": [36], 
 "type":  [12,13,14,15]
}
```

help me make a query in laravel to search for records that have, for example: color = [17, 23]

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: Probably answered here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320711/search-a-mysql-column-with-a-json-string-for-a-specific-value

Comment: This might help you https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

where you gonna implement that search option ? in dropdown?
if you use it in blade dropdown go through this link
[https://www.webslesson.info/2017/02/live-search-json-data-using-ajax-jquery.html#:~:text=After%20loading%20JSON%20File%20data%20we%20want%20search,format%20and%20here%20we%20can%20search%20by%20](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/02/live-search-json-data-using-ajax-jquery.html#:%7E:text=After%20loading%20JSON%20File%20data%20we%20want%20search,format%20and%20here%20we%20can%20search%20by%20)

and if you going to search in controller/model use the steps mention below

first, use json_decode and convert it into an array then
use another variable to store what you goona filter then use below example to filter
[filtering json data in php laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68406860/filtering-json-data-in-php-laravel)